# Magento 2: How to make a block image as sticky header? with category?

Tags: magento2, sticky-menu

So, I was looking For Making A Block image, or extension sticky! But after searching a lot I found no solutions!!! what i have right now is?

[image: This Image Block with Categories Under This]

And I want whenever i start scrolling, 
I want my Tent Image sticky!! 
[image: Like This One!]

Okay, If this not possible forget about the categories. just make that tent sticky! which is a image block !!!

or give a good guideline for getting a sticky image header!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should figure out whether you want sticky or fixed:

- Sticky: Something is located in my page, but not at the top. When I scroll down, it will get *stuck* to the top of the page.
- Fixed: Something is located at the top of my page and will always be stuck at the top of my page.

To do a proper sticky effect, you need both CSS and JS. To do a fixed effect, all you need is CSS. Based on the screenshot with the tent always at the top, I think you want a fixed effect.

The following should work:

In your **layout.xml**:

```
<block name="tent.image" template="Vendor_Module::tent.phtml">
```

In your **tent.phtml**:

```
<img class="fixed" src="tent.jpg">
```

In **[theme_dir]/web/css/source/_extend.less**

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

And then be sure to flush your cache and your static files cache.